# Releasing memory when closing javafx web browser

Tags: java, memory, javafx-webengine

I have an issue with a simple application using JavaFX that opens a web page when clicking on an element of a list.

It is a really simple application that nevertheless uses around 100 Mb of memory just to display a list of tasks.
When I open one of the tasks of the list in the embedded browser provided by JavaFX, used memory increases drastically to ~400Mb which is enormous for such simple program.

The issue comes when I close browser window as memory is not released. It remains at around 350 mb.

As we have performance issues with this application, I'm trying to find a way to reduce memory consumption.

Do you know a way to release the memory after closing the browser window ? Does it work the same way as for tabs (JavaFX keeps reference of last closed tab as described here : [Closing JavaFX tabs doesn't release memory from ArrayLists and TableViews in that tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928294/closing-javafx-tabs-doesnt-release-memory-from-arraylists-and-tableviews-in-tha?rq=1)) ?

Here's the class that contains the browser :

```
public class CustomBrowser extends Region {

    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

    private Application application;
    private int loaded;

    public CustomBrowser(final String url, int width, int height, boolean debug, final Application application) {

        this.application = application;

        if(application.config.isProxyWebview()){
            System.setProperty("http.proxyHost",application.config.getProxyHost());
            System.setProperty("http.proxyPort",String.valueOf(application.config.getProxyPort()));
        }
        Authenticator.setDefault(new CustomAuthenticator(application.config.getProxyUsername(),application.config.getProxyPassword()));

        init(url, width, height, debug, application, true);
    }

    public CustomBrowser() {
        super();
    }

    private void init(String url, int width, int height, boolean debug, final Application application, final boolean autoclose) {
        //apply the styles
        getStyleClass().add("browser");

        // process page loading
        browser.setPrefWidth(width);
        browser.setPrefHeight(height);

        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
                new ChangeListener<State>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov,
                                        State oldState, State newState) {
//                        System.out.println("onChange : oldState="+oldState+" - newState="+newState);

                        if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                            loaded++;
                            if(loaded==2 && autoclose){
                                application.refreshAll();
                                Stage stage = (Stage) getScene().getWindow();
                                stage.close();
                            }
//                            JSObject win = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
//                            win.setMember("app", new JavaApp());
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

        // load the home page
        webEngine.load(url);

        //add components
        getChildren().add(browser);
        if(debug){
            TextField copyableUrl = new TextField(url);
            copyableUrl.setEditable(false);
            copyableUrl.getStyleClass().add("copyable-label");
            getChildren().add(copyableUrl);//new Label(url)
        }
    }

    public CustomBrowser(final String url, int width, int height, boolean debug, final Application application, final boolean autoclose) {
        init(url, width, height, debug, application, autoclose);
    }

    public String getUserAgent(){
        application.LOGGER.info("User Agent : {}", webEngine.getUserAgent());
        return webEngine.getUserAgent();
    }

    // JavaScript interface object
    public class JavaApp {

        public void exit() {
            Platform.exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some source code as well?

Comment: What is displayed in the browser? Does displaying another (i.e. - empty) page make any difference? What OS are you using? Does this happen on multiple machines and multiple OS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436498

Comment: Try to load an empty page when closing WebView. It helps sometimes.

Comment: adding "webEngine.load(null);" on close event listener worked as said in @G.Fiedler link. Thanks !